# Laravel 10: CSRF token mismatch, status 419 al tratar de acceder a un endpoint de un API REST

Tags: laravel, quasar

Estoy tratando de autenticar un SPA con un API construida en laravel 10

El dominio de mi SPA es `localhost:9000`

en `config/cors.php` agrego la direccion localhost:9000 en Allowed-Origins para permitir que se atiendan requests de ese dominio.

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:9000'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

Luego en `config/sanctum.php` vuelvo a agregar la direccion del SPA para autenticar con tokens CSRF a las solicitudes provenientes de esa direccion

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Stateful Domains
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Requests from the following domains / hosts will receive stateful API
    | authentication cookies. Typically, these should include your local
    | and production domains which access your API via a frontend SPA.
    |
    */

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:9000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),
```

Estoy usando Quasar framework, consecuentemente uso axios para hacer peticiones http
en la configuracion de la instancia asigno a la propiedad `withCredentials` el valor true para que todas las peticiones incluyan el token XSRF generado por laravel.

```
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import axios from 'axios'

// Be careful when using SSR for cross-request state pollution
// due to creating a Singleton instance here;
// If any client changes this (global) instance, it might be a
// good idea to move this instance creation inside of the
// "export default () => {}" function below (which runs individually
// for each client)
const api = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://sharedmarket.test' })

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  // for use inside Vue files (Options API) through this.$axios and this.$api

  app.config.globalProperties.$axios = axios
  // ^ ^ ^ this will allow you to use this.$axios (for Vue Options API form)
  //       so you won't necessarily have to import axios in each vue file

  app.config.globalProperties.$api = api
  // ^ ^ ^ this will allow you to use this.$api (for Vue Options API form)
  //       so you can easily perform requests against your app's API
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
})

export { api }
```

Para obtener el token CSRF hago una peticion al endpoint `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` recibo como respuesta el token en el encabezado `Set-Cookie` esta cookie deberia almacenarse automaticamente en el navegador, pero no aparece por ninguna parte, revise en devtools Application/Storage/Cookies y al parecer no se esta guardando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de obtener este token, hago una peticion a la ruta `/signup` para registrar e iniciar la sesion del usuario, y aqui obtengo una respuesta de error, `status 419, CSRF token mismatch`, no adjunto el codigo del controlador de esa ruta porque la peticion ni siquiera llega a ejecutar el metodo controlador de esa ruta, el error se genera antes, en el middleware que verifica las sesiones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como alternativa a este problema, intente migrar el proyecto del SPA a la raiz del proyecto laravel para que ambas aplicaciones estuvieran en el mismo dominio, pero no pude porque estoy usando laravel Homestead con vagrant, tenia en mente hacer un symlink de la carpeta `dist` de mi proyecto Quasar dentro de la carpeta `public` del proyecto laravel, cada vez que intente crear el link simbólico un mensaje de error era lanzado el cual es "Protocol Error" intente ejecutar el comando como super usuario y obtuve el mismo resultado.

En que parte me estoy equivocando?

En `Http/Kernel.php` ya he descomentado la clase `EnsureAllRequestsAreStateful`, fue de lo primero que me asegure al empezar a configurar la autenticacion para este proyecto.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando laravel Homestead tu IP de homestead siempre va a ser diferente a la IP de tu maquina física.

La cookie de sesion jamas se estaba guardando en el navegador porque el dominio de la SPA y el de la API jamas iban a coincidir.

Mi SPA la estoy trabajando en mi maquina fisica, no estoy haciendola dentro de mi maquina virtual.

el dominio de mi maquina homestead era `sharedmarket.test`, pero tambien `localhost:8000`, si hacia una peticion a `sharedmarket.test` jamas iba a ser almacenada la cookie debido a que el dominio `sharedmarket` es diferente al dominio de la SPA, que en este caso es la SPA construida con quasar CLI.

luego si hago la peticion a `localhost:8000` siendo mi SPA de la direccion `localhost:9000`, por alguna razon el encabezado `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` nunca se incluye y tengo un error de `CORS`, de echo pareciera que `localhost:8000` no es mi servidor de laravel porque si pongo cualquier direccion en el navegador. no obtengo nada, ni siquiera de las rutas que no estan siendo protegidas con autenticacion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces hacer peticiones de tu maquina fisica a tu maquina virtual usando la direccion `localhost:8000` no va a darte el resultado que quieres.

localhost es un alias que hace referencia a la maquina en la que estas, si haces una solicitud a `localhost:8000`, en este caso estaba diciendo 'has una peticion aqui mismo en puerto `8000`', la solicitud jamas llega a la maquina virtual.

Podia usar el dominio `sharedmarket.test` para hacer los requests? En este caso si, pero iba a tener problemas ya que al ser esa ip y la ip de mi maquina local diferentes (`192.168.56.56` una alias para `sharedmarket.test` mientras que mi spa esta en `localhost:9000`), las cookies de sesion jamas se iban a guardar ya que estan usando la politica `Same-Site=Lax`, el navegador jamas iba a guardar una cookie de un dominio totalmente ajeno a menos que estableciera `Same-Site=None` en las cookies de sesion del servidor, no creo que sea buena idea usar el valor None para tus cookies de sesion ya que facilmente podrian ser robadas.

Mi SPA construida en quasar tambien estaba siendo servida en la direccion `192.168.56.1:9000`, tambien podias acceder a ella con `localhost:9000`. lo que hice fue darle un nombre de dominio a `192.168.56.1` en el archivo hosts de windows.

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Al final del archivo agregue lo siguiente

```
192.168.56.1 data.sharedmarket.test
```

Ahora esta direccion es considerada un subdominio de `sharedmarket.test` y puedo acceder a ella con el puerto 9000, `data.sharedmarket.test:9000`

Luego me voy a `config/cors.php` y modifico la propiedad `allowed_origins` para que tenga mi subdominio.

```
'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:9000','http://data.sharedmarket.test:9000'],
```

luego me voy a `.env` y agrego lo siguiente en `SESSION_DOMAINS`

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.sharedmarket.test
```

Ahora debes ir a `config/sanctum.php` y agregar el subdominio con el puerto a la lista de stateful domains.

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
    '%s%s',
   'localhost,data.sharedmarket.test:9000,localhost:9000,192.168.56.1:9000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
    Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
))),
```

Ahora cualquier subdominio de `sharedmarket.test` puede obtener cookies de sesion

Recuerda modificar tu archivo `quasar.config.js` en tu SPA para que el server de desarrollo de quasar sirva tu aplicación frontend en el subdominio, debes modificar el campo `host` de la propiedad `devServer`, si no esta presente, puedes agregarla.

```
devServer: {
  // https: true
  host: 'data.sharedmarket.test',
  open: true // opens browser window automatically
}
```

Esta es la unica forma en la que vas a poder comunicar tu SPA de quasar con un API laravel instalado en la maquina virtual Homestead, debes dar un subdominio a la ip en donde se esta sirviendo la SPA y además el subdominio debe coincidir con el dominio del servidor de laravel.